# SSH and redirection

Tags: bash, ssh

Consider the following command:

```
ssh aristotle sudo /bin/sh < test.sh
```

I want the redirection to apply to `/bin/sh` but it is consumed by sudo. Any ideas on how to achieve what I want?

Comment: This is not really a question for stackoverflow. However, can you clarify? Your command works fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just copy over test.sh and then invoke it?

```
scp test.sh aristotle:/tmp/test.$$.sh
ssh aristotle sudo /bin/sh /tmp/test.$$.sh
ssh aristotle rm /tmp/test.$$.sh
```

The $$ is the PID of the process on the local machine, giving some degree of randomness so your file doesn't get clobbered.

Answer (score 1):

Redirection *is* working with ssh and sudo! It only interferes with any password dialog from ssh and/or sudo.

So EITHER you don't use redirection, but workarounds like e.g. copying the script to the target machine first and then executing it (as e.g. @edoloughlin [suggested](https://serverfault.com/a/38025/165450)).

OR you configure ssh and sudo to not prompt for a password. Then it works like a charm:

```
$ echo "hostname" | ssh -A orwell sudo /bin/sh
orwell
```

There are thousands of howtos explaining how to use ssh passwordless, so i don't explain that part. And as for sudo, there are several ways to use it passwordless. @jtimberman [suggested](https://serverfault.com/a/38164/165450) to allow the user in question passwordless sudo in general (via sudo's `NOPASSWD` feature, see [sudoers(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers)).

I personally use the PAM module [pam-ssh-agent](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pam-ssh-agent/). It allows sudo to authenticate against a forwarded ssh agent and only falls back to password-based authentication if no ssh agent is available. On Debian & Ubuntu just

```
apt-get install pam-ssh-agent-auth
```

and then configure as documented in [pam_ssh_agent_auth(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_ssh_agent_auth).

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
ssh aristotle sudo /bin/sh -c "/bin/sh \\< test.sh"
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried your suggestion but sudo still seems to be consuming the redirection when it prompts for the password.

Comment: I have found that things work very differently when a shell is invoked from ssh than they do on a local command line and I am trying to determine what the (apparently) undocumented rules really are.

Comment: UPDATE: sudo is not consuming the redirection. sudo will not prompt for a password w/o a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

```
houdini@www ~ % sudo "echo foo >> ~houdini/foo.$$"
sudo: echo foo >> ~houdini/foo.30055: command not found
houdini@www ~ % ls ~houdini/foo*
zsh: no matches found: ~houdini/foo*
houdini@www ~ % sudo -s "echo foo >> ~houdini/foo.$$"
houdini@www ~ % ls ~houdini/foo*
-rw------- 1 root root 4 Jul  8 20:16 /home/houdini/foo.30055
houdini@www ~ % sudo -i "echo foo >> ~houdini/foo.$$"
houdini@www ~ % ls ~houdini/foo*
-rw------- 1 root root 8 Jul  8 20:17 /home/houdini/foo.30055
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `ssh somehost sudo cat \< /etc/passwd` with some success; try something like:

`ssh aristotle sudo /bin/sh \< test.sh`

Answer (score 0):

Likely, sudo is prompting for a password and its trying to get it from your test.sh script.

There's two solutions.

First, you can assign NOPASSWD for your userid on the target system.

```
 your_username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Or second, you can ssh to the system and provide a password to sudo, then run it again and

```
$ echo "your_password" | ssh remote_host sudo -l
your_username@remote_host's password:
[sudo] password for your_username: 
User your_username may run the following commands on this host:
    (ALL) ALL
$ ssh remote_host sudo /bin/bash < test.sh
remote_host.example.com
```

Of course, you'll want to take precautions about your password appearing in your shell history (such as put it in a file only you have access to, then get the value from that file via cat or similar).

I strongly prefer the former, with SSH key-based authentication only, no passwords at all, and the private key residing on one system: my laptop (protected with a 16+ character passphrase).

Contents of my test.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
hostname -f
```